# Is there anything like NVELO Dataplex (hybrid SSD/HDD software) for OS X?

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, ssd, performance

I'm interested in upgrading my old MacBook to using an SSD and moving the data drive to where the DVD drive is using an optibay.

Often SSDs come with a licence for NVELO Dataplex software (which is windows only). This software is basically a windows driver that keeps track of commonly used files and moves then to the SSD, thereby giving you a hybrid SSD.

**Is there anything like NVELO Dataplex for OS X** or should I just put OS X and applications on the SSD, and put home folders on the HDD using symbolic links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been thinking the same since I learned about Nvelo Dataplex and recently I stumbled upon [ssdcache](http://www.ssdcache.com/)

It looks like they are working on versions for Mac, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for. I'm thinking about participating in the beta

Comment: This answer is obsolete now, the linked site in the answer is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but for the benefit of anyone who comes across it: Apple introduced this capability under the name **Fusion Drive** in late 2012. Officially you can only get a Fusion Drive as a build-to-order option on a new Mac, but many people have reported success with [configuring their own](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69538/can-i-make-a-diy-fusion-drive) using the `diskutil` Terminal command in OS X 10.8.2 or later.