# Mountain Lion on Unibody late-2008 Macbook?

Tags: macos

I'm currently having a late-2008 Unibody Macbook with Snow Leopard installed. It runs really great!

However, I'm thinking of installing Mountain Lion. Mainly to use Filevault 2.

Will my Macbook run with ML?

It has the following specs:

```
2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo 
4GB 1066 MHz DDR3 
40GB Intel 320 SSD
```

Answer (score 1):

Your system specs are above the minimum requirements, so you should be fine. Lion and Mountain Lion do require more than the 2 GB RAM than Snow Leopard needs to run smoothly, in my experience. You've already got 4 GB, so that should be okay for all but the most busy systems with many large apps running simultaneously.

Comment: I would second the general statement that most people are happy with Snow Leopard and 2 GB RAM and about half feel 3 GB is the right amount of RAM for Mountain Lion (and in practice almost no one has 3 but instead jumps to 4). Your Mac should be very snappy even with 2 due to the Intel SSD and I would seriously look at adding a spinning drive to your optical bay if you are interested in not only FileVault 2 but a [DIY Fusion Drive](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69538/can-i-make-a-diy-fusion-drive) if you would like more space than 40 GB for your files, Apps and OS.

Answer (score 1):

Your specs look good. I have a 2005 MBP and really the only place I suffer is HD write speeds bottleneck. A RAM upgrade would be highly recommended and relatively inexpensive if you plan to have many apps running simultaneously. My personal experience is that you will suffer from performance issues and some interesting glitches (icon drag, display sleep problems) unless you do a clean install.

Answer (score -2):

I did and ruin my computer was very slow and the wifi worked poorly