# OS X Mountain Lion does not boot after the creation of a Fusion Drive

Tags: efi, core-storage, fusion-drive

I have followed a guide to set up the core storage logical volume to use one SSD and one HDD.

Since then, I have encountered multiple errors such as:

- `69822 Couldn’t rediscover disk after operation`
- `69780 Unable to create a new CoreStorage Logical Volume`
- ...

When created my Fusion Drive, I inverted `disk0` (HDD) and `disk1` (SSD) in the first command to create a Logical Volume Group.

If I boot normally (not in safe mode), the machine hangs at Apple logo ... even if I try to boot from an external drive or a Mountain Lion startup drive.

Could this be a problem of the EFI version (2.7)?

<sup>Hardware: Macbook Pro 15" early 2011 (8,2)</sup>

Comment: First, I'd recommend starting in verbose mode, by holding command and v when you turn the computer on:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492

Comment: I will try to edit this to make clear you created a DIY fusion drive - but please edit in a link to the procedure you used since we might catch a syntax or logical error and report **verbatum** the error messages so that others can consult their notes and see what might be different...

Comment: OK - there are two big problems here. 1) No work is shown, so no one can reproduce your situation without documentation of what exactly you did to set up your DIY "Fusion Drive". 2) You say the Mac won't boot from a known good external drive - how have you determined that the Mac isn't having a hardware failure on the storage bus or the attached storage?

Comment: You question is very vague and unspecific. What guide did you use to create the Fusion Drive? What is the 'first command' that you speak of?

Comment: It's my fault, but without a mac is quite difficult to post here. I used this guide: http://jollyjinx.tumblr.com/ and http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=16338598#post16338598. So, the first command is diskutil cs create Fusion disk1 disk0, the second one is  diskutil corestorage createvolume LVG_UUID MacintoshHD jhfs+ 610g.

Comment: For the external drive...if I have the internal HDD and internal SSD formatted separately it work perfectly. When I create the Fusion drive with the internal HDD and SSD nothing else boot! If I destroy the Fusion Drive, the external drive work perfectly.

Comment: With the verbose mode I see: IOAHCIBlockStorageDriver: Could not recover SATA HDD after 5 attempt, terminating _and_ disk0s3: no such device _and_ CoreStorage::recover()PV UUIDCODE From group "fusion" (UUIDCODE) has been marked missing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that some early 2011 15" Macbook Pro  (8,2) machines have trouble creating a Fusion Drive.

It's being discussed in this MacRumors forum thread: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1480179&page=16. This is the post that gives more datailed information about the problem http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=16321849&postcount=384

It might be a hardware problem, there is no known solution yet.

**Update:** I have just created a working Fusion Drive on my early 2011 15" 2.3Ghz Macbook Pro (8,2), following the instructions in the answers here: [Can I make a DIY Fusion Drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69538/can-i-make-a-diy-fusion-drive) I have installed Mountain Lion on it.
I used a 250GB Samsung 840 Pro in the hdd bay and placed the original 750GB hdd in place of the optical drive. Maybe the hardware troubles are only present in the 2.0Ghz versions.

Comment: @Matteo Which processor does your MBP have? 2.0, 2.2, 2.3 Ghz?

Comment: Intel i7 quad core 2.2. Why?

Comment: It seems that the chipset in the 2.0 version might be slightly different from the 2.2 and 2.3 versions. There is at least one success reported in the thread above with a 2.3 machine.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault, I've an Intel 17 quad core 2.0. So, where I can find details about my chipset?