# Added a 128GB SSD to 27" iMac

Tags: backup, imac, ssd

I've added a 128GB SSD to my mid 2011 27" iMac and **replaced** the defective original HDD with a new one (1TB). Used Time Machine as back-up.
How do I transfer ALL my data (about 620GB) to the two new drives (from TM)
 using the SSD for the OS (Sierra) and the HDD for everything else.
What´s the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Create a 3rd-party Fusion drive with the 128 GB SSD and the 1 TB HDD and restore your backup. Then you don't have to mess around with a 1:n file system split. TM just isn't made for this if OS and data (e.g. your main user) wasn't separated previously. It is possible though by restoring the backup to the HDD and then rsyncing all folders except your user (=data?) folder to the ssd, probably blessing the ssd system, linking your hdd user folder to the ssd and deleting the rsync'd source files and folders in a second step.

Comment: Thanks for the help klanomath; next big Problem for me is how to create a 3rd-party Fusion drive? I am no mac expert. Is it safe?

Comment: [Can I make a DIY Fusion Drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70113/93229)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Awesome information.I´ll try my best (keeping fingers crossed)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [HDD enclosure](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/external-hard-drive-enclosure) to connect it via USB.

Comment: I Just want to transfer myTime Machine image back-up to the "new" machine, using the SSD for the OS (Sierra) and the HDD for everything else...